# How to know div contents is empty or not for a specific div id in each function?

Tags: jquery

I need to check a specific div id content is empty or not in each function. If div content is empy I want to put there a "Please click to here for add a image" text message. But my code didn't worked.

I have a html like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="list">
<div class="item"><div id="image">image</div></div>
<div class="item"><div id="test">test</div></div>
<div class="item"><div id="image"></div></div>
<div class="item"><div>test</div></div>
<div class="item"><div id="image"><a href="test.html"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x75.png"></a></div></div>
</div>
</div>
```

How can I do like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="list">
<div class="item"><div id="image">Please click to here for add a image</div></div>
<div class="item"><div id="test">test</div></div>
<div class="item"><div id="image">Please click to here for add a image</div></div>
<div class="item"><div>test</div></div>
<div class="item"><div id="image"><a href="test.html"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x75.png"></a></div></div>
</div>
</div>
```

My Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".list #image").each(function() {
if($(this).is(':empty')) { $(".item #image").html("Please click to here for add a image"); }
});
});
```

My jsfiddle code is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/nmw4bad6/

Comment: id should be unique, so use class and update selector

Comment: Also in your example, the first `#image` div is not empty, yet had its content replaced anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".list #image").each(function() {
  if($(this).html()=="") { $(this).html("Please click to here for add a image"); }
 });
});
```

You also can change your code like below

```
if($(this).is(':empty')) { $(this).html("Please click to here for add a image"); }
```

Comment: a lot of thanks for your answer and code. This way a little bit a more good short solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues in your code

1. Using duplicate id's it should be unique in a context only the first one get selected in this case. Always use `class` for grouping multiple elements.
2. Even if it's empty you are updating all element by selecting all(`$(".item #image").html(..)`) elements(even though it won't select in your current code).

---

To make it work use class for grouping elements and then use [`:empty` pseudo-class selector](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) to get empty elements. Actually, there is no need to use [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method in your case since you want to update all elements with the same content.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".list .image:empty").html("Please click to here for add a image");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="image">image</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div id="test">test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div>test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="image">
        <a href="test.html"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x75.png"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE :** In case you don't have access to the backend code and need to work with duplicate id's then use [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) instead of [id selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and do the same.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.list [id="image"]').html("Please click to here for add a image");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="item">
      <div id="image">image</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div id="test">test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div id="image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div>test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div id="image">
        <a href="test.html"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x75.png"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: a lot of thanks for your answer and code. I need use div id istead of div class name at this time. But your answer is very helpful for class name solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have just modified your code so you can get your results.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".list > .item").each(function() {
var tag = $(this).children('#image');
if(tag.length)
{
    if(tag.html().length===0)
{
    tag.html('Please click to here for add a image');
}

}
});
);
```

Comment: a lot of thanks for your answer and code. Your code is working too. Very helpful for diffrent way using div id solution.